# How to only accept numbers for multiple inputs

Tags: c++

I want the user to enter one value then another, for two variables. If their input is anything else than a number. They should get an error and the program loops back to the beginning. If there's a way so that the user enters both values. Then only after they've entered the two values for the two variables. The program checks if the value for both is a number and nothing else. Then it displays the stuff I want it to. But if they don't put in a number. An error pops up. I've seen some code on how to do this. But I couldn't figure out how to make it work for multiple inputs. Also the program still accepted non numbers. Like if you entered "50k". It will say you entered "50" and ignore that "k". I wish for it to not ignore that non number. Instead, make the user feel bad for doing so by displaying an error message. Here's my code.

```
//discordio
// EXAM 01
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int Load_cost = 50;
    const double Mile_cost = .50;
    int load = 0;
    double mile = 0;
    const double Mpg = 8;
    const double PerGal = 3;
    double total = 0;
    double fin1 = 0;
    double fin2 = 0;
    double fin3 = 0;


   cout << "Welcome to discordio's Shipping! Please fill out the following." << endl;

cout << "Number of loads: ";
cin >> load;

cout << "Number of miles: ";
cin >> mile;


fin1 = load * Load_cost;
fin2 = mile * Mile_cost;
fin3 = mile / Mpg * PerGal;
total = fin1 + fin2 + fin3;

system("CLS");


cout << cout << "\nWelcome to discordio's Shipping!  We welcome the opportunity to provide you with a quote." << endl << endl;
cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
cout << "Shipping fee" << setw(3) << ":" << setw(3) << "$ " << load * Load_cost << endl << endl;
cout << "Mileage" << setw(8) << ":" << setw(3) << "$ " << mile * Mile_cost << endl << endl;
cout << "Fuel Surcharge:" << setw(3) << "$ " << mile / Mpg * PerGal << endl << endl;
cout << "Total" << setw(10) << ":" << setw(3) << "$ " << total << endl;
}
```

This is what I got for the basics of my homework (Sorry if this doesn't meet the criteria of most). I just need help adding errors for when both inputs are not numbers. If your code requires me to use an extra header file, please tell me. I'm still pretty new to this so I won't know what to add. Hope I covered enough in my question. Also please add code in your answer. If you could, make your code work if I paste into the IDE. I learn from manipulating things to find different results. So show don't tell.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean with _both variables_ when your example shows only one, but if you mean another `int z` you can simply write `cin >> x >> z`.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not entirely clear, but here are some solutions to possible issues that you might have:

### a) Reading more than one number, one after the other, unrelated

In this case it's the best to extract the code to read and validate the input operation into a function, like:

```
template<typename T, typename Q, typename E>
T askForOne(std::ostream & out, std::istream & in, Q&& question, E&& error) {
  T value;
  out << question;
  while (not (in >> value)) {
    in.clear();
    in.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    out << error;
  }
  return value;
}
```

Then you can call this function to retrieve more than a single value from some stream:

```
int one = askForOne<int>(std::cout, std::cin, "Enter a number: ", "Invalid. ");
int two = askForOne<int>(std::cout, std::cin, "Enter a number: ", "Invalid. ");
```

### b) Reading more than one number, related

If you want to read multiple numbers, and only accept the input if *all* of them have been read, then you could use a function like:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N, typename Q, typename E>
std::array<T, N> askFor(std::ostream & out, std::istream & in, Q&& question, E&& error) {
  std::array<T, N> values;
  auto const scan = [&in, &values] {
    for (auto & value : values) {
      if (not (in >> value)) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  };
  out << question;
  while (not scan()) {
    in.clear();
    in.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    out << error;
  }
  return values;
}
```

This would try to get the specified number of values, and fail as soon as one isn't valid. Instead of using a constant, compile time of numbers one could also use a run time sized `std::vector`.

A small test of the above functions:

```
// in some function
using namespace std;
int one = askForOne<int>(cout, cin, "Int? ", "Meh. ");
int two = askForOne<int>(cout, cin, "Int? ", "Meh. ");
auto ints = askFor<int, 5>(cout, cin, "5 ints? ", "Meh. ");
cout << "one = " << one << endl;
cout << "two = " << two << endl;
cout << "ints = ";
copy(begin(ints), end(ints), ostream_iterator<int>{cout, ", "});
```

> **Int?** Haha
>
> **Meh.** 21
>
> **Int?** Ha ha ha
>
> **Meh.** Ha
>
> **Meh.** 42
>
> **5 ints?** 1 2 3 4 BUUUUUU
>
> **Meh.** 1 2 3 4 BUUU JA
>
> **Meh.** Ehm 1 2 3 4 5
>
> **Meh.** 9 8 7 6 5
>
> **one = 21**
>
> **two = 42**
>
> **ints = 9, 8, 7, 6, 5,**

([Live here](http://ideone.com/BiLvkH))

Comment: Could you please type out the full code. Like starting from a blank screen. It would be more helpful if I could copy and paste the code. Then mess around with it until I figure how it works. If I copy paste any of this it just gives me an error for every line. Sorry my knowledge of C++ is very basic and my homework for each chapter has almost nothing to do with that chapter.

Comment: I added a full, running example of above code. Look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp to find out what's contained in the headers, and how exactly these functions behave. (Learning to learn this on your own is a substantial part of learning programming).

Comment: Okay, I figured out how to get your top code working for me. But it still allows the user to enter a letter. type in "5f" for both inputs and you get this.
    Load: 5f
    mile: Invalid. 5f
    
    --------------------------------
    Process exited after 4.864 seconds with return value 0
    Press any key to continue . . .
I tried the bottom code but it tells me
"error: 'askForOne' was not declared in this scope". I feel that that's the only problem I have left.

Comment: When you type an 'f', then in the command line there's no (portable) way to disable that there will be an 'f' printed. This kind of control is done in user interfaces, textual or graphical. I don't really understand the rest of your comment. What is your code? What is its expected behavior?

Comment: I got the code working now but in the console, before the intended output. "0x47f864" shows up on top.

Answer (score 0):

cin is a object declared in iostream 
it has a function named by ">>" .
so what you have to do is called operator overloading.
in this you change the defination of function defined by ">>"
but you can't overload it for cin since its class i.e iostream's constructor is not accessible so make another class derived from iostream than overload ">>" then make a object of it and use ">>" with that
for more info go to google and search about operator overloading

Comment: Some sample code might make this answer a little easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting the code into a function with an int parameter and passing in the two variables like so:

```
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    int z = 0;
    inputNumber(x);
    inputNumber(z);
}  

void inputNumber(int input)
{
    cout << "Enter an int: ";
    while(!(cin >> input)){
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cout << "Invalid input.  Try again: ";
    }
    cout << "You entered: " << input << endl;
}
```

Comment: You need to pass the `input` as reference: `int & input`

Comment: @DanielJour: even better, just return an `int`: `int inputNumber()`.